# Proof concave-up function on R must be positive at some point

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives, proof-writing

How can I prove that if a continuous function $f$ with domain $\mathbb{R}$ is concave up over its entire domain (i.e. $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$), then we must have $f(a) > 0$ for some $a$?

Maybe we can proceed by contradiction, assuming that the function is confined to $f(x)<0$ (below the $x$-axis) then show that it's not possible? I'm not sure...

How do I prove this?

Thank you.

Comment: You could use the fact that any tangent line lies below the graph of $f$.

Comment: So basically I have to show that there is a point where $f'(x)$ is nonzero. This means that there is a non-horizontal tangent line to the graph.

Then, I must show that this line extends towards $+\infty$ at one extreme value of $x$ and show that $f(x)$ is above the line?

Comment: Yes, find such a line.  I assumed you already knew the "tangent line formulation" of convexity (it is not hard to prove if you first observe that if $f''>0$, then $f'$ is increasing).